# Google Cloud SQL Read replica's in other regions within platform

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, region, google-cloud-platform, read-replication

I am looking to have a Cloud SQL MySQL instance have a read-replica in another region - within Cloud Sql.

I'm aware I can create an 'external replica' but I'm unaware / unable to create an 'external replica that is Cloud Sql'.

It would be very ugly to have a master sitting on the "Managed Service Cloud SQL", and be forced into a VM Mysql, in other regions.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Looking at add read-replicas in other regions for increased web app speed.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL does not currently support read replicas in a different region that the master instance.  As you mention, a self-managed replica can be used.